# Moving Lampp htdocs

Tags: apache, permissions, lampp

I have installed Lampp on Ubuntu 12.04LTS. I tried to move my htdocs to home/myusername/lampp/htdocs by editing both DocumentRoot values in httpd.conf.

After doing so I get Access Forbidden on all the pages.

I have tried chmod 755 on the directory, but that is already the default on the home directory, and predictably had no effect.

**Edit**

chmod 755 on all directories below htdocs solved the forbidden issues. I can now see the default XAMPP page @ localhost/xampp/index.php, and my test.html page under localhost/test.html.

localhost/xampp/index.php does not function as per normal however, and clicking any of the language links does not lead to the standard Xampp configuration and introduction page, instead doing nothing.

**Edit**

Once again the permissions were at fold. Using the recursive chmod is basically all that needed to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi sounds like a permission is at fault here, go into the home folder and CHMOD the folders ensuring that they are readable, and executable. Additionally you could add the user to the www-data and see if that resolves the issue but I doubt that's the case.

Ensure that you are using the -R command on the chmod this will set it to recursively do all the folders and all the files. Since 755 on folders doesn't unlock the actual files itself and they will remain unreadable.

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /home/username/lamp/htdocs
```

Comment: I have tried all three, still same issue. Permissions on /home/ were already 755, chmod g+w made no permission difference on /home/myusername/lamp/htdocs/ and sudo useradd -G www-data myusername says my user already exists.

Comment: Just updated it. The only reason you'd be getting those messages is that Apache2 can't get access as you know so it has to be a setting on the permissions that is cock blocking it.

Comment: Okay I redid the permissions and it was one of the subdirectories as you said. Now I can see the XAMPP language selection page but it does not allow me to go to the normal xampp setup page as usual. The 'English' link just appears to not work.

Comment: Again, the permissions I missed on one of the folders. The -R worked. THanks!